# Twitter api request using simple NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: objective-c, twitter

I am trying to get a user latest twits , with a simple request but getting a code error 400 .

What am i missing with my request body ?

```
    NSString *consumerKey = @"api key";
    NSString *consumerSecret = @"api secret";

    NSString *consumerKeyRFC1738 = [consumerKey stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                                    NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *consumerSecretRFC1738 = [consumerSecret stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                                       NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSString *concatKeySecret = [[consumerKeyRFC1738 stringByAppendingString:@":"]    stringByAppendingString:consumerSecretRFC1738];

    NSLog(@"-%@",concatKeySecret);
    NSString *concatKeySecretBase64 = [[concatKeySecret dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];



    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest
                                    requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=2"]];




    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:[@"Basic" stringByAppendingString:concatKeySecretBase64] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    NSString *str = @"grant_type=client_credentials";
    NSData *httpBody = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [request setHTTPBody:httpBody];


    //NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: &response error: nil];

    if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)])
    {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [response allHeaderFields];
        NSLog(@"%@",dictionary);
        NSLog(@"%@",response);

     }
```

The respond giving me this :

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x10cc21ba0> { URL: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=2 } { status code: 400, headers {
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 86;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
.....
....
```

Comment: Why aren't you using SLRequest?

Comment: is it more simple ? do you have a complete example ?

Comment: My goal is only to get the last twits of a certain page. thats it. i don't need to write to twitter, only read latest ..

Comment: I'd say its simpler, but let me show you and you decide if it fits your needs. One caveat is that the app should have permission to use the twitter account, if it doesn't it will ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

If it suits your needs, I'd recommend you using SLRequest. Please note that this framework will ask for permission to use the user's account.

```
NSURL *showUserURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{ @"screen_name": @"thestrayhotdog" };

SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                        requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                  URL:showUserURL
                                           parameters:parameters];
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (granted) {
        NSArray * accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
        if ([accounts count]) {
            ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accounts firstObject];
            request.account = twitterAccount;
            [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *connectionError) {
                NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
                NSLog(@"Status code: %ld",(long)[urlResponse statusCode]);
                NSError *error = nil;
                id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];

                if (error) {
                    // Handle error
                }
                // success;
            }];
        }
    }
}];
```